# Can i get a input as a list in python?

Tags: python, list

Hi first of all i am new to this site if i make any mistakes please excuse my mistake
I want to get a input from the user like [["x","y","z"],["1","2","3"]] and want to treat as its a list.I have tried to turn the string to list but it is pretty hard to do. Is there anything can i do thanks!
My code was this:

```
x=input()
y=input()
x=x.split(",")
y=y.split(",")
c=""
b=""
for i in x:
    c+=i
for i in y:
    b+=i

c=c.split("’")
b=b.split("’")
c = c[2:len(c)-2]
b =b[1:len(b)-1]
a=[]
d=[]
for i in c:
    a.append(i)
for i in b:
    d.append(i)
for i in c:
    if i == ' ':
        c.remove(' ')
for i in d:
    if i == '':
        d.remove('')
print(a)
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to implement the parsing yourself, just use an existing built-in function. In Python 3 is as simple as this:

```
import ast

list_as_string = input() # type a list like: "[1, 2, 3]"
lst = ast.literal_eval(list_as_string)

lst # this is an actual Python list!
=> [1, 2, 3]
```